# About integration and the convergence of series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've tried to solve a problem and there is a question I'm not sure about its answer:

What are the conditions for this equality to hold?

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\int_0^1 f_n(t,x)\ dt} = \int_0^1 {\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(t,x)\right)}\ dt$

I guess that the uniform convergence only needs for $t$ but don't needs for $x$. Is it true?

Comment: If for every fixed $x$ the convergence is uniform in $t$, that is sufficient. Another sufficient condition is that $f_n(t,x) \geqslant 0$ for all $n,t,x$, for example.

Comment: Can you explain why $f_n(t,x) \ge 0$ is sufficient condition

Comment: It's the monotone convergence theorem. It also holds for Riemann integrals with suitable interpretation, in case you're using the Riemann integral.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\int_0^1 f_n(t,x)\ dt} = \int_0^1 {\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(t,x)\right)}\ dt$ I would say you actually mean:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{D}:\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\int_0^1 f_n(t,x)\ dt} = \int_0^1 {\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(t,x)\right)}\ dt$$

If we denote $f_n(t,x)=g_n^{(x)}(t)$ then it means:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{D}:\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\int_0^1 g_n^{(x)}(t)\ dt} = \int_0^1 {\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n^{(x)}(t)\right)}\ dt$$

and you guess may be formally stated as:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{D}:\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n^{(x)}(t)$ converges uniformly to $G(t)$ for $t$ on $[0;1]$

Comment: Actually, it's what I mean. It's clear enough!